# Move short description into tabs in Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs, product

In woocommerce Single Product pages, how do I move the product short description into a custom product tab where the description and the additional information are?

I have moved the description and additional information tab from the standard position to the right side where the product summary is. However I would like to insert the product summary into a tab so essentially it will be 3 tabs.

The code I have used to move the tabs to the right of the image is:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 30 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still keep the following that change the tabs location (as you already do):

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 30 );
```

Then, the following will change the location of short description to a custom product tab:

```
// Remove short description
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );

// Add short description to a custom product tab
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'add_custom_product_tab', 10, 1 );
function add_custom_product_tab( $tabs ) {

    $custom_tab = array(
        'custom_tab' =>  array(
            'title' => __( "Short description", "woocommerce" ),
            'priority' => 12,
            'callback' => 'short_description_tab_content'
        )
    );
    return array_merge( $custom_tab, $tabs );
}

// Custom product tab content
function short_description_tab_content() {
    global $post, $product;

    $short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );

    if ( ! $short_description ) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">' . $short_description . '</div>'; // WPCS: XSS ok.
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: thanks! problem i have now is that it is duplicated at the bottom as well as the top right, how do i get rid of the bottom taps and only have it on the right?

Comment: @EmbroideryKing I don't know what you are talking about. This code is tested and works for what you asked…

Comment: this is my code currently. as you can see the tabs still show below. i would like them to not appear there but instead only on the right hand side of the picture. where as for the plugin called ppom, i would still like that to appear at the bottom. here is my code

Comment: @EmbroideryKing You need to keep your question code and add mine (like explained on my answer). Your initial question was to move short description into product tabs, which my code does.