# Hide WooCommerce product short description custom tab when its empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs, hook-woocommerce

I'm using *[Move short description into tabs in Woocommerce single product pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55308690/move-short-description-into-tabs-in-woocommerce-single-product-pages/55309387#55309387)* to move the Woocommerce product short description in a custom product tab.

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to unset the custom tab when there is no short description present.

How to hide WooCommerce product short description from a custom tab when its empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will hide this custom tab if product short description is empty:

```
// Add short description as a new custom product tab
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'add_custom_product_tab' );
function add_custom_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    global $post, $product;

    $short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );

    if ( ! empty($short_description) ) {

        $tabs['short_description'] = array(
            'title'     => __( "What's in the box", "woocommerce" ),
            'priority'  => 200,
            'callback'  => 'short_description_tab_content'
        );
    }
    return $tabs;
}

// Custom product tab content
function short_description_tab_content() {
    global $post, $product;

    $short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );

    if ( ! empty($short_description) ) {
        echo '<div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">' . $short_description . '</div>'; // WPCS: XSS ok.;
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.